# Why are there no "Store" context menu items for a Desktop app?

Tags: winforms, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a Windows desktop app that I want to make available on the Windows store, but there is no "Store" set of items in the Project's context menu (such as Store | Associate App with the Store, Store | Capture Screenshots, etc.

So is there a workaround, are even the Desktop apps required to be XAML (WPF) apps*, or am I looking in the wrong place, or what?

- This *is* a Winforms app, created with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a different process altogether, your app doesn't actually 'live' on the store, so much of the "Associate app with the Store" that happens with Windows Store apps isn't relevant.

Check this [Windows Store for Developer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx) blog post for the process.

Comment: The key point from that link (for me) is: "the developer is in charge of the (paid or free) acquisition experience" (when it comes to Desktop apps).